# Relay Pagination - Remove old nodes from store after cursor changed

Tags: pagination, graphql-js, relayjs, relay, react-relay

I implemented pagination system by using [pagination container](https://relay.dev/docs/en/pagination-container). It works great with one problem.

When i call loadMore function to get new nodes relay fetches nodes from server and adds to olds ones. But i want to delete old nodes and just want to show new ones.

For example $first = 10

When the page first loads i got 10 nodes, after loadMore i get 20 nodes. But i want to show just new fetched 10 nodes.

I used this [pagination example](https://relay.dev/docs/en/pagination-container#pagination-example)

I could not find a way to remove old nodes after loadMore action.

I know relay pagination intended to use only infinite scroll, i just wonder maybe there is a way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Hacky/easy solution is to alway map through the last 10 items.

Another solution is to check the Relay store using `ConnectionHandler` and delete the edges that you don't want from the store manually.

Look at `deleteNode` in https://relay.dev/docs/en/relay-store for more info how to work with relay store.

Better solution is to create a re-fetch-able container and use the cursor pagination instead so every time you get the next 10 items by setting the cursor and after arguments on the connection. This way you have to query for `pageInfo` and manually check if hasNextPage.

Also this way you will be able to have a bi-directional pagination (Forward and backward pagination).

More info about cursor based pagination:

https://relay.dev/graphql/connections.htm

https://graphql.org/learn/pagination/

Comment: i tried to perform manually delete node in relay store but it gets more complicated, probably the best way is to create my own pagination component as you said